# Manually calculating predictions using separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, model, regression

I developed a model and have a dataframe containing the features used and their coefficient:

```
feature    coefficient
intercept  2.5
a          0.5
b          0.8
c          1.7
```

I also have a dataframe containing completely new data:

```
a  b  c
1  0  2
0  1  3
```

I want to create a prediction for each observation using the formula:

```
intercept + a_coef*a_value + b_coef*b_value + c_coef*c_value
```

But I'm not sure how to manipulate both dataframes in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `intercept` in new dataframe, then do `dot`

```
s=df.set_index('feature')['coefficient']
newdf.assign(intercept=1).dot(s)
Out[249]: 
0    6.4
1    8.4
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the first dataframe has additional features that are not necessarily in the new dataframe (for now). This is giving me the error 'matrices are not aligned'. How would you filter the first dataframe down to the relevant features?

Comment: @hirshg  s=s.reinex(['intercept]+df.columns)